# How to fetch user specific data from firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an app where user can add their stock portfolio and see their profit and loss in real-time using google finance apis.

I allow the user to add their stocks and it is stored in a collection called `Stocks`

```
Stocks
  <user_id>: [
    {
      transactionType: "BUT/SELL",
      ticker: "APPL",
      quantity: 100,
      averagePrice: 500,
    }
  ]
```

Now when the user retrieves his portfolio, I only want to show his. I can just pull data from portfolio/ but how can I stop him from manually making a request and fetching/modifying other's portfolio?

Comment: As you've guessed from the tags on your question, security rules.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 1):

Your Firebase-based app authenticates with Firestore using an Firebase ID Token which is unique to every user that signs in into your app. Thanks to this, you can create **security rules** to prevent modifying other users data.

Here's the official guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started